# PhoneGap build - iOS not using config.xml

Tags: ios, cordova, configuration

I'm having a problem with [`PhoneGap build`](https://build.phonegap.com/). I'm using my own customized [`config.xml`](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml) packed together with my app in one zip file. The build process is successful except the iOS version. It works fine but it seems that is not using my `config.xml` at all. With Android there is no problem, the application has a proper icon configured in `config.xml`, but the iOS version uses the default `PhoneGap build` icon and configuration.

I tried to delete my browser cache when installing the IPA file, tried other iOS devices, but still it seems that the iOS version is using the default configuration instead of my customized one. Does anybody know the solution? Thx

Comment: Are you using Cordova with Xcode?

Comment: No I'm not using Xcode at all. I'm using only PhoneGap build cloud service. The application itself is written in Sencha Touch.